# Execute Cucumber Test scenarios using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, webdriver, cucumber

I am trying to run Cucumber test scenarios (java project) through Gradle by following reference link-https://docs.cucumber.io/tools/java/#build-tools

[This is my **Build.gradle** file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMTV4.png)

.[output of command **gradle build**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXOca.png)

this is showing scenarios are being recognized but WebDriver is not invoking and reports(build/tests/test/index.html) are showing zero.
I am very new to both gradle and cucumber and stuck in my first gradle project.
help will highly appreciated.

Comment: Are the stepdefinition methods inside the gradle.cucumber package?

Comment: stepdefination methods are locataed in my src/test/java/org/projectName/appname/tests/stepDeffile.java.

Comment: I am sorry but I  should mention it before that I am trying to execute this from command line and not using IDE in my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note- I got it with second another way is --> when we are using TestNG framework, in the `build.gradle` file we just need to add the following

```
test{ 
    useTestNG() 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the glue parameter in task from "gradle.cucumber" to the classpath where your stepdefinitions are present. Switch to `org.projectName.appname.tests` and try

`gradle.cucumber` was the location of the package of stepdefinitions specific to the article.

Comment: It works for me like I was not getting an error but not getting any output too...    Now ERROR is - C:\Users\darshana.patel\Desktop\New folder (3)\automationdemo>gradlew.bat clean cucumber

> Task :jar
:jar: No valid plugin descriptors were found in META-INF/gradle-plugins
> Task :cucumber
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.DuplicateStepDefinitionException: Duplicate step definitions in org.projectName.appName.tests.AuditingAuditStepDef.saved_report_equals_report_name(String) infile:/C:/Users/darshana.patel/Desktop/New%20folder%20(3)/automationdemo/build/classes/java/test/ and..

Comment: and Showing- * Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\darshana.patel\Desktop\New folder (3)\automationdemo\build.gradle' line: 60

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cucumber'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED in 2s
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed

Comment: The first one is just a warning "No valid plugin descriptors were found in META-INF/gradle-plugins". Not a big thing, ask someone who knows gradle, I got no idea how it can be fixed. Look at line 278 from gradle source which mentions this warning - https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugin-development/src/main/java/org/gradle/plugin/devel/plugins/JavaGradlePluginPlugin.java

Comment: Regarding second you have two stepdefinition methods which are matching the same step pattern. The two methods are mentioned in the error. Change one of the step patterns and the problem will go away.